# I am trying to display email consisting of html in React Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to display a page html in React Js But I don't get the same look This is the code I used in React js
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }}/>`
This is  the page when it's executed in html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfPdW.png)
This is  the page when it's executed in React js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpNIc.png)

Comment: These are two different emails

Comment: email here I mean the messages I receive and they are different in format ,so I want to display them whenever the site sends them

Comment: When I use dangerouslySetInnerHTML it should display messages as they were sent

Comment: Your own css is changing your inner html. Try to embed it as iFrame for example.

Answer (score 0):

I used tag iframe and it worked

```html
<iframe  srcdoc={data}/>
```